# Increse Pure-FTPd timeout on a Debian server

Tags: debian, ftp

I need to increse Pure-FTPd timeout on a Debian server.

On internet I have found out that I have to edit `/etc/pure-ftpd.conf`by changing the `MaxIdleTime`.

The problem is that I have no `/etc/pure-ftpd.conf` but an entire pure-ftpd directory, which content is:

```
# ls /etc/pure-ftpd/
auth  conf  db  pureftpd-dir-aliases  pureftpd.passwd  pureftpd.pdb
```

Comment: How about that `conf` right there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PureFTP configurations are a little strange. You should be able to set the timeout by adding a file called "MaxIdleTime" inside the conf directory. The content of the file should be the number of minutes you like to set the timeout to be. Afterwards just restart your server.

```
echo 10 > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/MaxIdleTime
```